# Android.app.Application cannot be cast to

Tags: android, global-variables

Despite i followed some StackOverflow's tips, I can't get rid of this error:

Android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.dostalgia.airshootingrogatti.GlobalClass

I inserted GlobalClass in manifest file, as already said in S.O.

**This is the Global Class Code:**

```
public class GlobalClass extends AppCompatActivity {


    private int StatoContatore1;


    public int getStatoContatore1() {
        return StatoContatore1;
    }

    public void setStatoContatore1(int statoContatore1) {
        StatoContatore1 = statoContatore1;
    }
}
```

**And this is the activity (Not the main) that calls and generate error**

```
package com.dostalgia.airshootingrogatti;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Postazione1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_postazione1);

        final GlobalClass globalVariable = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();


    }
}
```

**This is my Mainfest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dostalgia.airshootingrogatti">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Postazione1"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".GlobalClass"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

My goal is to use and manage global variables in different activities!

Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My goal is to use and manage global variables in different activities!

You are welcome to *carefully* use `static` fields. This would not require you to try creating a custom `Application` subclass, as you appear to be attempting to do here.

That being said, if you really want to do what I think you are trying to do:

Step #1: Have `GlobalClass` extend `android.app.Application`, not `AppCompatActivity`

Step #2: Remove the `<activity>` element in the manifest for `GlobalClass`

Step #3: Add an `android:name` attribute to the `<application>` element in the manifest, pointing to your `GlobalClass` class (e.g., `android:name="com.dostalgia.airshootingrogatti.GlobalClass"`)

Comment: Thanks! My Application is not crashing anymore. To be honest as I am at my first experience in programming I am using video-tutorial to achieve what It's in my mind, so I don't know at all what is the best way to do. I was also trying the database way, but It's quite difficult for me!